# Define Endpoints for each web service and contract in wcf

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, web-config

I have WCf application with4 webserivce with indivdual Interface as contract. so do i need to define endpoint, serviceBehaviors for each web service in config file? to access individual web service in single or multiple web applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Webservice can be exposed using one (i.e. one endpoint for all webservices) or multiple endpoints (i.e. one for each webservice). Each endpoint will have behavior,binding etc

If you go with 1st option client will have one proxy-contract for an endpoint.

In your case you can expose all four service interface using single endpoint.

Comment: ok so i need to define the common endpoint for each service and then how can i define different behavior for each service ?

Answer (score 0):

Each service must have a corresponding address, endpoint and binding definition. If you are using config files each service must be declared in a separate `<service>` node in the `<services>` collection.